# Using Wildcard to limit the function to take only class and its subclasses

Tags: java, generics

```
       public <T extends Exception> void testFunction(T  t) {

}
```

This is same as writing testFunction(Exception t). I used generics above just to show that java allows this.

But Java is not allowing to do the same using wildcards

```
        public void testFunction(<? Extends Exception> t) {

}
```

How can i use the wildcards here? There is no real purpose for doing this.But still wanted to see if there is a possible way from a syntax point of view.

Comment: `Integer` is a final class. you can't extend it.

Comment: If you want a method to be callable with a Foo, or any subclass of Foo as argument, the signature is simply `void someMethod(Foo foo)`. You don't need generics or wildcards for that.

Comment: Your title seems to indicate that you want to limit the type to only subclasses of something. But the generic example that you give doesn't actually do that (it allows the class itself). Can you clarify what you really want?

Comment: Why the downvotes? `Integer` was a poor choice, being `final`, but otherwise it's a good question.

Comment: I have clearly pointed out in the question that there is no real purpose of doing this. I don't need to use generics in the first place. But I am curious if there is syntax which allow me to do this using wildcards.

Comment: No there isn't. The key thing about wildcards is that they can only exist inside `<>` of a generic type, e.g. `List<T>` or `Comparable<T>`. Wildcards cannot exist anywhere else. Instead you can just use `Object` (which is like an unbounded wildcard) or a specific type for a bounded wildcard (e.g. `Number` instead of `? extends Number`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public <T extends Integer> void testFunction(T  t) { ... }
```

This function accepts an `Integer` or any subtype (if such could exist). It does *not* force you to supply a subtype of `Integer`. Therefore it accepts the exact same range of types as just

```
public void testFunction(Integer i) { ... }
```

There is actually no way to specify a strict subtype (an exclusive upper type bound) in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need generics for that (even if you replace `Integer` with a non-final class) :

```
public void testFunction(Integer t) {
```

Comment: The OP title seems to indicate that the only classes allowed are *subclasses* of the given type.

Comment: @RealSkeptic It sounds like OP might want want an interface

Comment: @RealSkeptic When you use generic type parameters with an "extends" type bound, the type that appears after the "extends" keyword can also substitute the generic type parameter, not just sub-classes of that type.

Comment: I'm well aware of that. But the OP may not be.